# IP Accounting display from SQL proper sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with the correct way query to display information from a database table.

My database table contains columns of id | src_address | dst_address | bytes

The information is stored from my MikroTik router (IP Accounting) but my script stores the IP addresses as integers so I can select ranges.

I need the correct query to run to display the data out as follows:

- All bytes that are shown from a src_address to dst_address will be the upload bytes
- All bytes that are shown from a dst_address to src_address will be the download bytes

(src_address -> dst_address = upload)

(dst_address -> src_address = download)

I need the script to output the exact following:
IP Address | Upload bytes | Download bytes | Total bytes

My current script only outputs the upload bytes and I am not sure how to reverse the order a second time to display the download bytes and then add both to display the total bytes.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//Include needed files
require ("config.php");
include ("includes/formatbytes.php");

//Connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($SQLserver, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, 
$SQLdatabase);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Query database
$query = "SELECT * , SUM(bytes) AS upload_bytes FROM ipaccounting WHERE 
src_address BETWEEN 3232235520 AND 3232301055 AND dst_address NOT BETWEEN 
3232235520 AND 3232301055 GROUP BY src_address";


//Execute query
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


//Display IP information
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>IP Address</th><th>Upload</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (isset($row['src_address'])) {
        $src_address = $row['src_address'];
        $src_address = long2ip($src_address);
    }
    /*if (isset($row['dst_address'])) {
        $dst_address = $row['dst_address'];
    } */
    if (isset($row['upload_bytes'])) {
        $uploadbytes = $row['upload_bytes'];
        $uploadbytes = formatBytes($uploadbytes);
    } 

    echo "<tr><td>".$src_address."</td><td>".$uploadbytes."</td></tr>";
} 

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Note that in integer 3232235520 is 192.168.0.1 and 3232301055 is 192.168.255.254

Comment: `SELECT * , SUM(bytes) AS upload_bytes FROM ipaccounting WHERE 
src_address BETWEEN 3232235520 AND 3232301055 AND dst_address NOT BETWEEN 
3232235520 AND 3232301055 GROUP BY src_address`... is a invalid SQL because off the `SELECT *.... GROUP BY src_address` it will get you random values  read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Please share the create table statement off the table ipaccounting and some example data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate twice, once for the uploads and once for the downloads:

```
SELECT address, SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes, 
       SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes
FROM ((SELECT src_address as address, SUM(bytes) AS upload_bytes, 0 as download_bytes
       FROM ipaccounting
       WHERE src_address BETWEEN 3232235520 AND 3232301055 AND
             dst_address NOT BETWEEN 3232235520 AND 3232301055
       GROUP BY src_address
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT dst_address, 0 AS upload_bytes, SUM(bytes) as download_bytes
       FROM ipaccounting
       WHERE dst_address BETWEEN 3232235520 AND 3232301055 AND
             src_address NOT BETWEEN 3232235520 AND 3232301055
       GROUP BY dst_address
      )
     ) a
GROUP BY address;
```

You can also display the ip addresses in a more reasonable format.  MySQL has IP address functions (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa)):

```
select . . . , inet_ntoa(src_address) as src_ip
```

You can also do this at the application layer.